# Create a Raspberry pi backup without dd

Tags: linux, backup

I would like to backup the entire content of my Raspberry Pi SD Card on  linux PC. I have found online many tutorials that suggest to use `dd` to perform the operation. However my SD Cards have a wide free space that doesn't require to be saved on backup, that is why I am searching for an efficient alternative to `dd` that would not backup free space.

Do you have any idea of such alternative software that could do this ?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit :** When I say I want to perform a backup, I mean I want to make a copy of the entire OS installed in the SD Card plus personnal data installed on. When I restore the backup on another SD Card, I should get a clone of the initial SD Card. Furthermore, the backup should be done with the Raspberry shutdown and the SD Card plugged in my PC.

Comment: Define "backup". This means different things to different people. Also try reading the hundreds of posts on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not satisfied with any of the previous answer, but I have now found a way that gives me entire satisfaction, using `Clonezilla` :

On another computer running Linux (in my case Ubuntu 18.04),

1. I installed clonezilla : `sudo apt install -y clonezilla`
2. I created the `/home/partimag` to store my backups (`sudo mkdir /home/partimag` )

When I want to backup the entire system of my Raspberry Pi, I shut it down, I unplug the SD card from the Raspberry Pi and I plug the SD card into my PC. Then,

1. I run Clonezilla as root: `sudo clonezilla`
2. I decide to work as `device-image`
3. And then I `skip` the step `Mount Clonezilla image directory`
4. I complete all the others steps to make the backup.

> This produces a compressed backup of the full content of the SD Card (OS + programs + documents + ...)

Answer (score 6):

There are at least two options to create bootable mSD clones, depending on whether you prefer a UI or the terminal:

1. pi clone which gets installed alongside with the Pixel desktop.
2. the `rpi-clone` script from https://github.com/billw2/rpi-clone, which does roughly the same job, but without any UI. Clone the GitHub repository, and `chmod u+x rpic-clone/rpi-clone`. Then ...

   - run `sudo rpi-clone/rpi-clone -f sda` the first time; this creates the necessary partitions and does a full rsync to ensure that you get a workable booting copy.
   - subsequent delta updates: `sudo rpi-clone/rpi-clone sda`.

Replace `sda` with your particular SD card reader/writer.

I'm solely using the `rpi-clone` script for many months now and I never had any issues. The only caveat: don't do a delta update to an mSD with an existing, different OS setup. Just use the `-f` option to ensure that you get a working clone in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, I was hoping to make this a comment instead of an answer but don't have enough (points?), anyways I've been taking the sd card out of pi putting it in a usb card reader/writer, then using win32diskimager to create an image from it.

Answer (score 0):

[raspiBackup](https://www.linux-tips-and-tricks.de/en/quickstart-rbk) is able to save only the used space even if you use a dd backup. Just read [FAQ #16](https://www.linux-tips-and-tricks.de/en/faq#a16)